# Could not load type namespace.global parser error on Deploying to IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis, global-asax

I am trying to deploy the Asp.net web application using Visual Studio web setup project.Every thing is going fine when trying to access the application from the browser i am getting this error..

```
Could not load type namespace.global.
```

Here is my global.asax file ..

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="DCMSWebSetup.Global" Language="C#" %>
```

And here is my global.asax.cs ..

```
namespace DCMSWebSetup
{
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{

    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup

    }
```

I searched on the web and tried following suggestions but in vain only..

```
1.Changed Codebehind to CodeFile
2.Checked Output path to /Bin which was already there only.
3.Changed Copy to output directory to copy always.
```

All these options are not working in my case.

What else can be wrong?

Comment: The dll is deployed on the IIS server? Is this a 32bits or 64 bits app? Are all assemblies that you have locally also available after deployment on IIS? Is the appdomain in IIS that is linked to the website enabled for 32bits applications? What does the eventlog tell you?

Comment: @rene Yes the dlls are on the IIS.Regarding 32 or 64 have no idea ..Yes all assembilies are available..

Comment: @rene What should be the directory structure of bin in IIS on deployment of the app

Comment: Just a bin folder with assemblies. Hunt down all the info I requested and add to your question...

Answer (score 1):

I used InstallShield to deploy my website on IIS and i got this kind of message.
I discovered that my package got the good .dlls but not in the good place. I needed my dlls in /bin subdirectory. InstallShield did not respect that. That's why i had this message about "unable to load  type ...global".